# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException in SAML implementation

Tags: exception, wso2

i am getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException when Setting Up SAML2 Based SSO.i refered this article.http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS410/Setting+Up+SAML2+Based+SSO#SettingUpSAML2BasedSSO-SingleSign-OnInReality .
I am getting response but its not in xml format.any help to fix this issue??

thanks

Comment: Please specify where you are facing problem. Might be some code or the exception.

Comment: [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)

Comment: getting this exception during the log in time

Comment: Are you able to resolved this error? I am also facing same error. Please do the needful.